# Is it possible to save command output from browser's console by using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Let's say I have some auto-test, which goes to some website and executes command in browser's console by using Javascript executor.
For example, this command:

```
var updates = require('model/updates');
updates.lastCheckedFrontendUpdateTime();
```

And for example I have following output from this console command:

```
1530002781
```

And I want to save this output to some variable for latter use in auto-test. Is it possible to somehow "catch" this output and save it by using Selenium or some other tool ?

Comment: which language you are using?

Comment: supputuri, Java